# The variable name '@' has already been declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Part of our solution is a page that displays company-specific information using an ASP `Gridview`. Our method of constructing the SQL that feeds the `Gridview` is by using C# to build a custom `SELECT` statement based on a series of user inputs.

Once the user applies their filters through a `button click`, C# loops through all of their selections (`check boxes and text boxes`) and then propagates those selections to a separate method which constructs a `WHERE` clause to append to a simple `SELECT` statement. We use a `Table-Valued Function in the FROM statement`, and the only input parameter is from the `Querystring` and this does not change throughout the process.

Once the query has been assembled using C#, we apply this query to the `SqlDataSource` as the `Select Command`. However, we have recently discovered a very bizarre SQL error that we haven’t seen before:

**Errors :**

`"The variable name '@' has already been declared`.

`Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.`"

We aren’t declaring any variables in our SQL. As stated above, the only input parameter comes from the `Querystring`, and we access this parameter using both `QueryStringParameters` in the `ASP:SqlDataSource` on the ASP side and “`int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]).ToString()`” on the C# side while constructing the SQL query.

After researching this error, I have yet to find an instance where the variable declaration is empty. Most people are getting errors similar to this when they have declared a variable such as `'@email' or '@address'` twice. We have no double declarations, and the fact that the variable in the error is not defined is causing a massive headache.

Has anyone seen anything like this before or have any suggestions on how to further debug?

I'll post some code if need be, but we are mostly interested to see if anyone has seen an error like this before.

**Code**:

```
string MainQueryStr = ResultsPages.SearchString(SearchVariables(), Request,
                ProjectsSqlds, 0, "SELECT DISTINCT dbo.{0}.* FROM dbo.{0}(" + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]).ToString() + ")", 
                "getXyzById", "AbcId");
        StringBuilder SearchQueryStr = new StringBuilder();
        SearchQueryStr.Append(MainQueryStr);
        SearchQueryStr.Append(" ORDER BY AbcName");
        ProjectsSqlds.SelectCommand = SearchQueryStr.ToString();
```

The search string function is a 500 line method that we can't post right now. It is used all over our solution and works as it should. It stitches together strings to create the query.

This is how the SearchString function appends the parameters:

```
 l.Add(ResultsPages.NewSearchQueryString(ABCFiltersTxBx, SearchQueryStringVariableType.String,
            "{1}.AbcID IN (" + ABCFiltersTxBx.Text + ")"));
```

Where the ABCFiltersTxBx is parsed into a comma separated string.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated SQL of the queries that are causing errors?  I'd start there, and look for anywhere that a `@` is used.  My guess is that the cause of the error will become rather apparent.

Comment: Yes we have looked at the SQL when that page loads and nothing breaks, and after the Where clause is appended and nothing breaks there either.

Comment: So when does it break?  What does the SQL look like at that point in time?

Comment: It breaks at the databind for the gridview. If we set a break point right before that and pull the sql string, it runs properly. The SQL statement looks exactly is you would think it would, one variable declaration in the FROM clause for the TVF, and a few WHERE clause's after that.

Comment: post your code from the construction of the query string up until databind.

Comment: I have re-posted what my supervisor will allow at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should chime in as the supervisor in question here:

OK, so we figured out what was happening.

What we didn't realize was that the SQLDataSource was taking our appended WHERE clauses and using them as SelectParameters. Each parameter we wanted to add to the query that would ultimately feed the SQLDS was then being added as a SelectParameter without us realizing it, and because we hadn't made any explicit parameter declarations, the parameters were added with just "" as the name, leading to the error of "'@' has already been declared".

The most embarrassing part of this whole thing is that our API has already accounted for Parameter Names, but we had unwittingly excluded this part. Thank you all very much for reading and attempting to help. We thoroughly appreciate you taking your time to help us brainstorm our solution over here.

So I suppose the take-home of this whole error is in 2 parts:

1. Know your API. When you realize that you screwed it up on your own, graciously thank those that took the time to help you here on StackOverflow (or wherever you seek help), as their time is valuable as well.
2. "'@' is already declared" would indicate that you have parameters being declared without a name, so when debugging, look through the SQLDS you are using and find any parameters that haven't been explicitly named.

Again, thank you to all who read and offered to help. It's greatly appreciated.